# Apache-Tomcat 7 Http Status 404

Tags: java, xml, servlets, deployment, tomcat7

I've built this very basic servlet and trying to run it with Tomcat7[Ubuntu 14.04]. But I keep getting Http Status 404 not found error.

**Info:**

CATALINA_HOME in `/usr/share/tomcat7` and CATALINA_BASE in `/var/lib/tomcat7`.

> **Deployment Structure**: Deployed in CATALINA_BASE as follows:

```
webapps
\
 ROOT
 \
  BeerV1
  \
   index.html
   WEB-INF
   \
    web.xml
    classes
    \
      tk
      \
       sjsbook
       \
        web
        \
         BeerSelect.class
```

> web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyBeer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tk.sjsbook.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyBeer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Whenever I run the servlet `BeerSelect` from index.html as `SelectBeer.do`, the container gives 404 error.

```
<form method="POST" action="SelectBeer.do">
```

Please Suggest!!

Comment: please add the link from `index.html` which contains the URL to `MyBeer` to your question

Comment: I see that you deployed `BeerV1` under `ROOT`, that's wrong. You have to deploy it in webapps

Comment: @Ulrich - I think the container is set to webapps/ROOT by default, as on opening `localhost:8080` in browser, webapps/ROOT/index.html gets opened

Comment: after installation of tomcat, `ROOT` contains the default homepage of tomcat. This is the page where you see the version of tomcat, the link to the manager application and other informations. This what you see when you enter `http://localhost:8080` in your browser. You should deploy your webapp to `<TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/BeerV1`. If you wantyour webapp  to be the default application, then delete the directory `ROOT` and rename your webapps war from `BeerV1.war` to `ROOT. war`, and deploy it. I wouldn't do this

Comment: I was unaware of this. Thanks @Ulrich